# Laplace correction with conditions for smoothing

Tags: python, pandas, smoothing, outliers

I have a data (user_data) that represent  the number of examples in each class (here we have 5 classes), for example in first row, 16 represent 16 samples in class 1 for user1, 15 represent that there is 15 samples belong to class 2 for user 1, ect.

```
user_data = np.array([
    [16, 15, 14, 10, 0],
    [0, 13, 6, 15, 21],
    [12, 29, 1, 12, 1],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 55]])
```

I used the following method to smooth all these frequencies to avoid issues with extreme values (0 or 1) by using Laplace smoothing where k=2.

[image: Laplace smoothing]

Output:

```
array([[0.29824561, 0.28070175, 0.26315789, 0.19298246, 0.01754386],
       [0.01754386, 0.24561404, 0.12280702, 0.28070175, 0.38596491],
       [0.22807018, 0.52631579, 0.03508772, 0.22807018, 0.03508772],
       [0.01754386, 0.01754386, 0.01754386, 0.01754386, 0.98245614]])
```

But I want to smooth only extreme values (0 or 1) in this data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have noticed that your smoothing approach will cause P > 1, you are to clip or normalize the values later on:

```
probs = user_data/55
alpha = (user_data+1)/(55+2)
extreme_values_mask = (probs == 0) | (probs == 1)
probs[extreme_values_mask] = alpha[extreme_values_mask]
```

Result:

```
array([[0.29090909, 0.27272727, 0.25454545, 0.18181818, 0.01754386],
       [0.01754386, 0.23636364, 0.10909091, 0.27272727, 0.38181818],
       [0.21818182, 0.52727273, 0.01818182, 0.21818182, 0.01818182],
       [0.01754386, 0.01754386, 0.01754386, 0.01754386, 0.98245614]])
```

Extension:

```
# Scale by sum.
probs /= probs.sum(1).reshape((-1, 1))
print(probs)
print(probs.sum(1))

[[0.28589342 0.26802508 0.25015674 0.17868339 0.01724138]
 [0.01724138 0.2322884  0.10721003 0.26802508 0.37523511]
 [0.21818182 0.52727273 0.01818182 0.21818182 0.01818182]
 [0.01666667 0.01666667 0.01666667 0.01666667 0.93333333]]
[1. 1. 1. 1.]
```

Comment: thank you, could you extend your solution to include a clip or normalize the values?

Comment: I have added the scaling by the sum.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `np.where`, which follows the format `np.where(condition, value if condition is true, value if condition is false)` – feel free to read the documentation [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html).

For example:

```
S = 55
k = 2

np.where((user_data/S == 0) | (user_data/S == 1), (user_data+1)/(S + k), user_data/S)
```

Result:

```
array([[0.29090909, 0.27272727, 0.25454545, 0.18181818, 0.01754386],
       [0.01754386, 0.23636364, 0.10909091, 0.27272727, 0.38181818],
       [0.21818182, 0.52727273, 0.01818182, 0.21818182, 0.01818182],
       [0.01754386, 0.01754386, 0.01754386, 0.01754386, 0.98245614]])
```